# How to stop pyspark from automatically renaming the duplicate columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a csv file with duplicate columns in it. When I read with spark.read.format("CSV").load(). It automatically renames the columns with index value appended in the last of column name.

```
""df=spark.read.format('csv').option('header',True).load('desktop/csv/2.csv')""
display(df)
```

[image]

Any idea on how to get the column names as year, year_1

Answer (score 0):

From the following link https://dbmstutorials.com/pyspark/spark-dataframe-schema.html there is the solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType # imported StructType

schema_def = StructType()  # Created a StructType object
schema_def.add("db_id","integer",True)      # Adding column 1 to StructType
schema_def.add("db_name","string",True)     # Adding column 2 to StructType
schema_def.add("db_type_cd","string",True)  # Adding column 3 to StructType

df_with_schema = spark.read.csv("file:///path_to_files/csv_file_with_duplicates.csv", schema=schema_def, header=True)

df_with_schema.printSchema()
```

You should create the dataset schema before loading your file, in this way you can override the default duplicate name that Spark returns.

Comment: Creating the custom schema is great. But when we have more than 1000 columns its gonna take more time. Do you suggest anything for that, and that will be really helpful

Comment: Since you know how spark manages the duplicated columns, just use in someway df = df.withColumnRenamed("Year_1", "new_name")

Answer (score 0):

Using Custom schema you can load csv file with renamed columns

```
>>> schema = StructType() \
...       .add("Year",StringType(),True) \
...       .add("Year_1",StringType(),True) \
...       .add("Industry_code_NZSIOC",StringType(),True) \
...       .add("Industry_name_NZSIOC",StringType(),True) \
...       .add("Units",StringType(),True) \
...       .add("Variable_code",StringType(),True)

>>> df = spark.read.option("header",True).option("inferSchema",True).schema(schema).csv("/dir1/dir2/Sample2.csv")

+----+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+
|Year| Year_1|Industry_code_NZSIOC|Industry_name_NZSIOC|           Units|Variable_code|
+----+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+
|2020|Level 1|               99999|      All industries|Dollar(millions)|          H01|
|2020|Level 1|               99999|      All industries|Dollar(millions)|          H04|
|2020|Level 1|               99999|      All industries|Dollar(millions)|          H05|
|2020|Level 1|               99999|      All industries|Dollar(millions)|          H07|
|2020|Level 1|               99999|      All industries|Dollar(millions)|          H08|
+----+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Creating the custom schema is great. But when we have more than 1000 columns its gonna take more time. Do you suggest anything for that, and that will be really helpful